# Python LXML Parsing

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm using python to parse an xml file like the following:

```
   <infoTable>
       <nameOfIssuer>3 D SYSTEMS CORPORATION NEW</nameOfIssuer>
       <titleOfClass>COM</titleOfClass>
       <cusip>88554D205</cusip>
       <value>1044</value>
       <shrsOrPrnAmt>
           <sshPrnamt>88292</sshPrnamt>
           <sshPrnamtType>SH</sshPrnamtType>
       </shrsOrPrnAmt>
       <investmentDiscretion>SOLE</investmentDiscretion>
       <otherManager>100</otherManager>
       <votingAuthority>
           <Sole>0</Sole>
           <Shared>0</Shared>
           <None>150</None>
       </votingAuthority>
   </infoTable>
```

I'm parsing thousands of xml files that have some number of `<infoTable>` blocks in them. If there is a larger number of `<infoTable>` blocks in my file, then it stops reading the `<value>` tag and its contents.

Has anyone come across an error like this?

For reference, my code in python using the lxml parser is the following:

```
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(fileName, events=("start", "end")):

    tag_name = elem.tag.split("}")[1].strip()

    if not elem.text:
        text = "None"
    else:
        text = elem.text.strip()

    # Do something with tag_name and text
```

Has anyone come across an error like this before? I'm not sure if memory is the issue since I've tried the same code and same xml file on multiple computers and it gives me the same error. Additionally, when I take out the offending block of xml and run the same code on that block, it works fine. Not sure what else to be looking at this point.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is "a larger number"? What does "an error like this" mean? What is the actual error?

Comment: When I try to process a file of say 4000 infoTables, the value field isn't parsed. Instead of getting the number (in this case, 1044), it gets a None type.

Comment: 4000 infoTables is about a 4MB file, so not that big

Comment: What is `elem.tag.split("}")` supposed to do? None of your tag names contains a `}`.

Comment: It adds in the namespace, so I use the split statement to just get the tags.

Comment: The XML in the question has no namespaces. Why does the code need to "add in the namespace"?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's one of my problems. There's no reference to namespaces in the file. However, it still adds in the namespace, which is why I need the `elem.tag.split("}")`. The original file contains the namespace. I pull out just the infoTable sections and put them in a new file, removing all namespaces. When I parse this new file, the namespaces are still there and I'm not sure why.

Comment: When you say "it still adds in the namespace", what exactly is "it"?

Answer (score 3):

lxml works fine, even for [a file containing 4,000 `infoTable` elements](https://www.lhorn.de/so.xml). I'd use [XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) to get the text of the `value` elements:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("so.xml")

for value in tree.xpath("/root/infoTable/value"):
    print(value.text)
```

The output contains 4,000 rows of `1044`.